# Winson with timestamp not adding timestamps

Tags: node.js, winston

I created a simple Winston logger for my node application, but the configuration with timestamps not working, what it means? It means that all of the logs isn't with the timestamp.

Example:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const logger = createLogger({
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            maxsize: 5120000,
            maxFiles: 20,
            filename: `logs/logs.log`,
            colorize: true,
            json: true,
            timestamp: true
        }),
        new transports.Console({
            level: "debug",
            timestamp: true,
            format: format.combine(
                format.colorize(), 
                format.simple(),
                format.timestamp()
            )
        })
    ]
});


module.exports = { logger };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`simple()` format does not output timestamp. so you should define a custom format using `printf`:

```js
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

const myFormat = format.printf(({ level, message, label, timestamp }) => {
  return `${timestamp} [${label}] ${level}: ${message}`;
});

const logger = createLogger({
    transports: [
        new transports.File({
            maxsize: 5120000,
            maxFiles: 20,
            filename: `logs/logs.log`,
            timestamp: true,
            json: true,
        }),
        new transports.Console({
            level: "debug",
            timestamp: true,
            format: format.combine(
                format.timestamp(),
                format.colorize(), 
                myFormat,
            )
        })
    ]
});


module.exports = { logger };
```

i also moved `timestamp()` format before the myFormat as it should fill timestamp of message before it reaches the printf.

Comment: Hi. I'm back with another question. The timestamps are showing but aren't added in file .log - is there any solution for adding timestamps into the log file too?

Comment: i updated the code for file timestamps. i also removed colorization from file transport as you should not put color info in the file (use it for console only).

Comment: the only difference is that you should move timestamp: true before json: true

Comment: I made a second myFormatFile and with string templates create an object, this is working but I don't have an idea if it is a good way